# Converting Unicode apostrophe in php

Tags: php, unicode

So I’m getting some text from a user in PHP and one of the characters is supposed to be an apostrophe but instead of coming in as the character apostrophe `’` it comes in as `%u2019`.

I tried all of the following to no avail:

```
$b = urldecode($a);
$c = utf8_decode($a);
$d = html_entity_decode($a);
$e = rawurldecode($a);
```

This `%u2019` seemingly can’t be turned back to this character.

urldecode: %u2019

utf8_decode: %u2019

html_entity_decode: %u2019

rawurldecode: %u2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be JavaScript escaped string. You can see the same string if you run `escape("’")` in your browser console.

Use my php function that is equivalent to JavaScript `unescape()`:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback(
          '/%u(\d+)/',
          function($matches) {
              return mb_convert_encoding('&#'.hexdec($matches[1]).';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
          },
          $str
       );
```

If your php is older than php 5.3, you should define the callback function as a normal function because older php can't support closure.

Comment: This worked the! I had to look up preg_replace_callback

$str = $a in my example but this worked great!